# Enviar información entre formularios

Tags: html, c#, linq, razor, session

No puedo mantener la información de los formularios para posteriormente tratarla y hacer una consulta a la base de datos con linq.

```
        @{

            <form class="form" method="post">

                @{ 
                    var clientQuery = from PEL_T_Clientes in dbDatos.PEL_T_Clientes
                                  orderby PEL_T_Clientes.Nombre ascending
                                  select new { PEL_T_Clientes.Nombre, PEL_T_Clientes.Apellidos };}

                 <select>

                    @foreach (var client in clientQuery)
                     {
                         <option value="">@client.Nombre @client.Apellidos </option>
                     }

                 </select>

                <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar datos" />

             </form>


            if (IsPost)
            {

                <form class="form" method="post">

                    @{ 

                        var filmQuery = from PEL_T_Peliculas in dbDatos.PEL_T_Peliculas
                                        orderby PEL_T_Peliculas.Titulo ascending
                                        select new { PEL_T_Peliculas.Titulo };
                    }

                    <select>

                        @foreach (var film in filmQuery)
                         {
                            <option value="@Request.Form[film.Titulo]">@film.Titulo</option>
                         }

                    </select>

                    <input class="submi" type="submit" value="Enviar datos" />

                </form>

            }
        }
```

¿Cómo podría mantener los valores seleccionados en el  depués de hacer ambos submit? Si pudieran adjuntar explicación y/o documentación sobre variables de *session* sería perfecto. Actividad didáctica. No puedo usar web Forms o MVC.

Comment: a donde hace submit el form ? Si estas programando con asp.net mvc, ese codigo es incorrecto, no respetas el patron definido en la arquitectura de esta tecnologia

Comment: Estoy programando en asp.net mvc pero el problema es que aún no me ha dado el modelo vista controlado. El submit del form ha de hacerse a otra página con otro form. Cito el enunciado: Dada una tabla, seleccionar un valor de uno de los campos mediante un elemento ComboBox que estará previamente relleno con todos los valores posibles. Al seleccionar una, provoca la aparición de un nuevo elemento ComboBox que presentará los elementos posibles para la selección anterior, y al elegir un valor de este segundo, aparecerá una tabla con todos los valores posibles con dichas dos selecciones anteriores.

Comment: what? no te han dado el modelo vista controlador? pero si esto ya lo defina la propia tecnologia, nadie tiene que darte nada

Comment: lo que quieres hacer esta claro, pero no estas implementando la tecnologia de forma correcta, aconsejaria primero leas algo de asp.net mvc y veras que no esta bien la forma en como quiere hacer la implementacion, mas alla de lo que te hayan dado o no, lees un poco, internet esta lleno de tutoriales simples para aprender, y veras lo que estoy comentando